# Centos 7.0 can't start network service

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, centos7

**I get this error when I start network service**

> ```
> Job for network.service failed because the control process 
> exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" 
> and "journalctl -xe" for details.
> ```

```
[root@server ~]# systemctl start network.service
Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@server ~]# systemctl start network
Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@server ~]# ^C
[root@server ~]# systemctl status network.service
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2013-11-09 20:19:50 EET; 18s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8799 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com network[8799]: RTNETLINK answers: File ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com network[8799]: RTNETLINK answers: File ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com network[8799]: RTNETLINK answers: File ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com network[8799]: RTNETLINK answers: File ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com network[8799]: RTNETLINK answers: File ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com network[8799]: RTNETLINK answers: File ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com systemd[1]: network.service: control pr...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring ...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com systemd[1]: Unit network.service entere...
Nov 09 20:19:50 server.hostistore.com systemd[1]: network.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I can only access the internet with dhclient at the moment. I made the ip address settings but it didn't work. It was working before, I had this problem when I reset the server's bios settings, I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

Network settings

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp3s0
UUID=7ce98357-0726-4466-9936-b8e8aeccd563
DEVICE=enp3s0
ONBOOT=yes
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
IPADDR=192.168.1.38
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
```

Comment: For starters, please follow the hint your system gives you and use the `-l` option to see the complete and much longer lines of the (warning/error) output: `systemctl status -l network.service`

Comment: One of the things that jumps out though: your clock is ten years out of date judging by `Sat 2013-11-09 20:19:50 EET; 18s ago` - No idea if that explains your difficulties though